# why copying object in java is not working?

Tags: java

I have to copy an object by value not by reference, I tried different methods, but none are working. Please take a look at this code:

```
public static class25 copy(class25 otherSpec) {
    class25 class2 = new class25( otherSpec.Getfct());

    for (pa pack : otherSpec.Getfct())
        class2.addsp(pack);
    for (dn ddata : otherSpec.getdld())
        class2.addsp(data);

    return class2;
}
```

And it's use:

```
class25 class22 = class25.copy(class2);
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the library you are using? Its not possible to answer the question without knowing that this library does.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Does it make monkeys fly out of your nose or burn down your house?

Comment: Also, if you're trying to use the method that is inherited from Object its called "clone()".

Comment: you can copy by doing this since this.dummy = another.dummy; // you can access

Comment: @PeterLawrey.. If its a library, then that code won't even compile. It violates the Java Naming Convention/

Comment: @limelights.. Its better to use a `Copy Constructor` than using `clone` method. See [this chapter of Effective Java](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/java/9780137150021/methods-common-to-all-objects/ch03lev1sec2#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODAxMzcxNTAwMjElMkZjaDAzbGV2MXNlYzQ=)

Comment: To help you in every possible manner, we at  least need to know if you are the author of the class  GLMLabelSpecification? Moreover, if that is the case, can you paste the source of this class.

Comment: And one  more thing. Please don't just go to deep sleep just after you have asked a question on SO. People here wait for your reply.

Comment: @dosfly Before post next time don't post the actual code rather that prepare with the test sample.

Comment: I voted to close as it seems the OP does not want to provide any feedback...

Answer (score 1):

Maby the `GlmLabelSpec.AddSpecificationPage`doesnt  really clone the content but manage a reference list, so it stores only the reference to the same subobjects.